# Validating datetime-local input in Django 1.9 Form

Tags: django, html, forms, validation, datetime

The HTML5 input datetime-local returns it's value in %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M format.  Notice the T between the day and hour.  I've added that to the field in the form like this:

```
end = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, input_formats='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
```

and the template manually creates the field:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="id_end" name="end" value="{{ form.end.value }}">
```

Inspection of the request reveals the form data does indeed send the field in a format matching the validator: `2016-04-06T17:18`

So what is the format validator returning a validation failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `input_formats` parameter is a list not a string(as the name implies). Please check the django doc about [DateTimeField input_formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats).

> input_formats
>
> A list of formats used to attempt to convert a string to a valid
>   datetime.date object.

Comment: You were right. I didn't have brackets around my single item list.  But django didn't throw any errors at me either, so I figured it was fine.  Good Catch.

Comment: is there a way to globally specify input_formats? trying this:
from django.conf.global_settings import DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS += ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',) don't seem to have any effects